# How to check if the database exists or not in rails before doing a rake db:setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How to check if the database exists or not in rails before doing a rake db:setup?

I would like to check if a database already exists before a db:create is being done . I have not seen a specific way in rails so far but i know this can be done using mysql scripts

Comment: Why do you want to? `rake db:create` will not fail even if the database already exists. It prints a message saying that the message already exists

Comment: i am running a chef cookbook that does that ...so the cookbook stops after that message. I want it to skip the rake db:create and continue if the database exists

Comment: Is it raising an exception? If so you can put it in a begin rescue block and continue on this error

Answer (score 40):

Here is a method that checks if the database already exists:

```
def database_exists?
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection
rescue ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError
  false
else
  true
end
```

**References**

- [ActiveRecord::Base.connection](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionHandling.html#method-i-connection)
- [ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NoDatabaseError.html)

Comment: I've turned the [Dwayne Crook's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/391924/dwayne-crooks) [solution above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25592558/1300227) into a gem: [activerecord-db_exists](https://rubygems.org/gems/activerecord-db_exists). Hope it helps. :)

Comment: This is the best solution because it specifically rescues the error in question `ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError`. Other errors may reflect a bad connection, wrong port, wrong host, wrong password, etc - in which case we don't want to continue running db commands.

Answer (score 33):

I made a rake task that expands on some of the previous answers. I use this a lot in a Vagrant+Docker setup, so I can very easily issue a single command and either create a new database or issue a migrate to the current database. I use a [branched database](https://github.com/consolo/branchy) paradigm for development. I constantly need to seed a new database or update my existing one.

In lib/tasks/db_exists.rake:

```
namespace :db do
  desc "Checks to see if the database exists"
  task :exists do
    begin
      Rake::Task['environment'].invoke
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection
    rescue
      exit 1
    else
      exit 0
    end
  end
end
```

So now I can run a simple bash command:

```
rake db:exists && rake db:migrate || rake db:setup
```

Which I have then further automated into a Makefile (trimmed for brevity):

```
.PHONY database
database:
        rake db:exists && rake db:migrate || rake db:setup
```

Translates into:

```
make database
```

For all of my local database needs.

Comment: Instead of `Rake::Task['environment'].invoke`, can you do `task :exists => :environment`?

Comment: No, because I don't want the execution of a prerequisite task to fail before I have a chance to trap the error and return silently. The intention of this task is to see if it works and then silently return a 0/1 status, and you have to wrap the call to the environment task in the begin/rescue block in order to check for pass/fail status and not get a giant screen full of backtrace.

Comment: Just a word of caution here. It's better to rescue a specific error as opposed to rescuing StandardError (which is the default for rescue method without arguments). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048173/why-is-it-bad-style-to-rescue-exception-e-in-ruby for more.

Comment: Maybe you want the environment task to fail, just to be sure you have your environment properly setup when executing this task. I would have written `task exists: :environment do` to avoid the invoke.

Answer (score 19):

You can also count on the fact that `rake db:migrate:status` returns an error if the database does not yet exist.

I'm using something like this in my scripts:

```
(rake db:migrate:status 2>/dev/null || rake db:setup) && rake db:migrate
```

(Inspired by [penguincoder]

Comment: I would strongly recommend against doing this. If your db:migrate command fails for any reason then the setup command is run. db:setup will truncate any existing error so if your migration fails for any reason, you lose all your data,

Comment: @JamesRocker I adapted the answer so it is using `db:migrate:status` instead. 
Although the `db:init` part of `db:setup` will not cause you to lose your data, the seeding and migration part of it might render errors, and hiding information using `rake db:migrate 2>/dev/null` can be a PITA.

Answer (score 11):

Rails 6 now has a `rails db:prepare` task.

`db:prepare` will run `db:migrate`. If `db:migrate` fails, then `db:create`, `db:seed`, followed by `db:migrate` are run.

See all rails tasks with `rails --tasks`

```
...
rails db:exists                             # Checks to see if the database exists
...
rails db:prepare                            # Runs setup if database does not exist, or runs migrations if it does
...
rails db:setup                              # Creates the database, loads the schema, and initializes with the seed data (use db:reset to also drop the database first)
...
```

NOTE:
`db:setup` will remove any data currently in the database.
See [Joshua Pinters's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/293280/joshua-pinter) [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150064/how-to-check-if-the-database-exists-or-not-in-rails-before-doing-a-rake-dbsetup/66591524?noredirect=1#comment125033641_66591524).

Comment: Note, `rails db:setup` will remove all the data in the database, if it exists already. I didn't find that super intuitive, especially considering the comment at the end of the line: "(use db:reset to also drop the database first)".

Answer (score 8):

Here are some bash scripts I made for this purpose:

### Postgres

```
if echo "\c $PGDATABASE; \dt" | psql | grep schema_migrations 2>&1 >/dev/null
then
   bundle exec rake db:migrate
else
   bundle exec rake db:setup
fi
```

### Mysql

```
 if echo "use $MYSQLDATABASE; show tables" | mysql | grep schema_migrations 2>&1 > /dev/null
 then
     bundle exec rake db:migrate
 else
     bundle exec rake db:setup
 fi
```

These check for the presence of the `schema_migrations` table to determine whether `rake db:setup` has been run previously.

Answer (score 6):

This will return false if the DB doesn't exist or if the connection is not active (at least in Rails 4+).

```
::ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection(&:active?) rescue false
```

Answer (score 1):

My version in bash:

```
database_version() {
    local DB_VERSION=$(bundle exec rake db:version 2>/dev/null)

    if [[ "$DB_VERSION" =~ ^Current\ version\:\ ([[:digit:]]+)$ ]]; then
        if [[ "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" != "" ]]; then
            echo $(("${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"))
        else
            echo -1
        fi
        return
    fi

    echo -1
}

if [[ $(($(database_version))) > 0 ]]; then
    echo "Database exists"
else
    echo "Database does not exist"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS**

```
 IF EXISTS 
       (
         SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases 
        WHERE name = N'New_Database'
        )
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'Database Name already Exist' AS Message
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        CREATE DATABASE [New_Database]
        SELECT 'New Database is Created'
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use to check the state of the DB:

```
if db_version=$(bundle exec rake db:version 2>/dev/null)
then
    if [ "$db_version" = "Current version: 0" ]; then
        echo "DB is empty"
    else
        echo "DB exists"
    fi
else
    echo "DB does not exist"
fi
```