# Error trying to change database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm following a tutorial to change the database depending on the subdomain, the subdomain must be the name of an existing database to which the system will connect as shown in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GRfJ9lni4QA) at 15:30 minute and works quite well, The problem comes when the system is accessed with a subdomain whose database does not exist, showing me the following error: `Cannot open database "another_database" requested by the login. The login failed`
and displaying the error does not allow access to the system, regardless of whether it is accessed with the name of an existing database in the subdomain unless the rails server is restarted.

This is my code in my ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :connect_to_database


  def connect_to_user_database(name)
    config = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations["development"].merge("database" => "#{name}")
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)
    #auth = name
    #raise auth.to_yaml #podemos ver los datos que nos ofrece el parametro
  end


  private

  def connect_to_database
    connect_to_user_database(request.subdomains(0).first)
  end

end
```

Comment: For security and to avoid errors, you should check if subdomain is valid before `connect_to_database`.

Comment: @wesley6j thanks for answer, but how can I check if the database exist?

Comment: If you have a list of subdomains that you want to use, save the array somewhere in your codebase or config file.

Comment: Are you able to `rescue StandardError render file: "#{Rails.root}/public/404", layout: true, status: :not_found end`

Comment: @wesley6j Thank you very much, it worked

Answer (score 0):

Using something like what is done in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25592558/8088139
build a catch situation to fail gracefully if the database doesn't exist

something like

```
def connect_to_user_database(name)
  config = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations["development"].merge("database" => "#{name}")
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)
rescue ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError
  clear_cache!
  #set response to forbidden
  #log the failure
end
```

EDIT: added clear_cache! to NoDatabaseError rescue

Comment: Thanks for replying, I pasted the code but it still shows me the same error

Comment: Try running this command in the rescue case
  "clear_cache!"

editing answer with this

Comment: I placed your code and I started the rails server but I still get the same error when I enter the name of an existing database when I first enter a database that does not exist.

Comment: Then I would suggest what wesley6j suggested, creating a white list of acceptable subdomains, and not even attempting a db connection if the incoming domain isn't in the whitelist

Comment: Thanks, I'll go for that option.